# Is there a way to convert a python dictionary string with some values as python commands?

Tags: python

How to convert this to a dictionary?

```
params = "{'cat_features':[X.columns.get_loc(i) for i in cat_vars], 
'num_boost_round':100, 'eta':.01, 'reg_lambda':1.8, 'verbose':False, 
'loss_function':'MultiClass','early_stopping_rounds':5}"
```

without the first part `[X.columns.get_loc(i) for i in cat_vars]` I can run `ast.literal_eval()`, but that doesn't work if there is python code in the string. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you trust the contents of the string?

Comment: You can use the `eval` function instead, if you are sure that `X.columns.get_loc(i)` has no dependencies on external data source; otherwise the use of `eval` would introduce security risks.

Comment: But you want to execute the code inside or skip it?

Comment: This screams X-Y problem. Why are you dynamically executing a string as python code? Why not create a *function* and call that function?

Comment: This is reading a dictionary from a config file. By default the values are read as strings. I need to convert the string into an evaluation... and yes... i can trust the contents of the string but that's not what I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plain `eval`.

However, **using `eval` is is risky if the string comes from an non-trusted source** because a properly crafted string could execute anything on the computer where the program is running.